# How can i display a nested box inside the terminal using python with minimum codes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The user will be asked to enter any positive number and the output will be the following:

If he enters '1':

```
***
* *
***
```

If he enters '2':

```
*******
*     *
* *** *
* * * *
* *** *
*     *
*******
```

If he enters '3':

```
***********
*         *
* ******* *
* *     * *
* * *** * *
* * * * * *
* * *** * *
* *     * *
* ******* *
*         *
***********
```

And so on. That means if the input is 'n', the output will be 'n' number of nested box in the following pattern.

PS:

Here I've tried some codes. But not getting the desired pattern.

```
try:
    n = int(raw_input("Please Enter A Positive Number: "))
    list = range(1, 4*n)
    if n > 0:
        for n in list:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                print "*" + " " * (list[-1]-2)  + "*"
            else:
                if n:
                    print "*" * list[-1]
                else:
                    pass
    else:
        print "You must choose any positive number."
except:
    print "You must enter a number."
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Any code to share?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: In order to receive useful answers you need to show that you've made some effort to solve the problem yourself. Please show your code.

Comment: yeah i've tried but unable to do so

Comment: Can you write a program that just prints a simple un-nested box of the right size?

Comment: Lol.
Sorry I really can't. @PM 2Ring 
The above code work for only one box though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function to add a nesting layer to an existing `box` and then call this the required number of times as follows:

```
def add_nested(box):
    new_box = []
    lines = box.splitlines()
    width = len(lines[0])

    l1 = '*' * (width + 4)
    l2 = '*{}*'.format(' ' * (width + 2))

    new_box.extend([l1, l2])

    for row in lines:
        new_box.append('* {} *'.format(row))

    new_box.extend([l2, l1])
    return '\n'.join(new_box)

n = int(raw_input("Please Enter A Positive Number: "))
box = "***\n* *\n***"

for _ in range(n-1):
    box = add_nested(box)

print box
```

So if `5` was entered, it would display:

```
Please Enter A Positive Number: 5
*******************
*                 *
* *************** *
* *             * *
* * *********** * *
* * *         * * *
* * * ******* * * *
* * * *     * * * *
* * * * *** * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * *** * * * *
* * * *     * * * *
* * * ******* * * *
* * *         * * *
* * *********** * *
* *             * *
* *************** *
*                 *
*******************
```

**How does it work?**

The function first splits the existing box into lines and determines the width of the first line. It then creates two lines to go above and below the box (called `l1` and `l2`). These have the correct number of `*` and  for the new outer box. It then adds these to a list of lines. Then for each line in the existing box, it added `*` to the start of each line and `*` to the end. It then adds `l2` and `l1` to the end to complete the new nested box. It then returns this list of lines as a single string joined with newlines to create the new box. This function can then be called again and again to add further layers.

Answer (score 1):

The code below progressively builds the top left corner of a nested set of boxes. It builds the right side by reflecting the left side, and it builds the bottom by reflecting the top.

We start with an empty base string and alternately add a star (on even lines) or a space (on odd lines) to this base; the current half-row is constructed from the base string by padding it with a star or space as appropriate.

The `nested_box` function does no printing, it returns a list of strings, so it's up to the calling code to do the actual printing.

```
def nested_box(n):
    w = 2 * n
    rows = []
    base = ''
    for i in range(w):
        c = '* '[i % 2]
        base += c
        row = base.ljust(w, c)
        rows.append(row + row[-2::-1])
    return rows + rows[-2::-1]

# Test
for i in range(1, 5):
    print('\n', i)
    for row in nested_box(i):
        print(row)
```

**output**

```
 1
***
* *
***

 2
*******
*     *
* *** *
* * * *
* *** *
*     *
*******

 3
***********
*         *
* ******* *
* *     * *
* * *** * *
* * * * * *
* * *** * *
* *     * *
* ******* *
*         *
***********

 4
***************
*             *
* *********** *
* *         * *
* * ******* * *
* * *     * * *
* * * *** * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * *** * * *
* * *     * * *
* * ******* * *
* *         * *
* *********** *
*             *
***************
```

To run this code correctly on Python 2, put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the script. That's really only necessary for the `print('\n', i)` call, the box printing doesn't need it.

---

Just for fun, here's a "code golf" version:

```
def b(n):
 r,a=[],''
 for i in range(2*n):c='* '[i%2];a+=c;l=a.ljust(2*n,c);r+=[l+l[-2::-1]]
 return'\n'.join(r+r[-2::-1])
for i in range(1, 5):print(i,b(i),sep='\n')
```